# Seeking Robust To-Do List Software

Tags: android, todo, task-management

I am looking to replace my current to-do list software (Google Tasks) with something significantly more full-featured.

Here are the features and properties I would need such software to have:

- subtasks
- task dependencies
- Android app with offline use
- either a Windows application or a web interface
- good synchronization of data
- notifications
- due dates and times
- total cost at most $10 US per month

And here are the features and properties I would very much like such software to have:

- open source
- free
- self hosted on a Linux VM or Docker image

I am looking for this for personal use, not as a business, so collaboration, sharing, and similar things are unimportant to me. I am also not in need of a simplified UI, although I would prefer to avoid a CLI if possible. Combining multiple apps/services is okay, although the fewer the better.

Comment: Just wondering: How goes "Linux VM or Docker image" together with the `android` tag? Guess that should be for the server part (sync/collaboration)?

Comment: Yes, the server part (basically just for sync) is what would be in the Linux VM or Docker image. The client part is what I need on Android and Windows/web.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/)?

It is very feature-rich (albeit I find its documentation slightly lacking), you can run a Taskwarrior server and it has a [pretty big ecosystem](https://taskwarrior.org/tools/)